# Can Hawtio Be USed To Browse JMS Messages In JBoss?

Tags: jboss, jms, activemq-artemis, hawtio

The JBoss managment console only shows you statistics about JMS queues (count etc).

I have a local application to browse the messages and I can configure HermesJMS to show the messages too.

However, I am trying to view the text content of the messages in a web browser so that support staff can relatively easily investigate issues.

When I install Hawtio I can only see a JMX MBean browser (a pretty set of MBeans though), which is confusing for the support team.

I am looking for something like the [ActiveMQ console](http://shengwangi.blogspot.ca/2014/10/quick-tutorial-on-activemq-web-console.html) that shows the messages as a grid and lets you click on them to see the message content.

Is this possible for JBoss using Hawtio? Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

hawtio has plugins for ActiveMQ and Artemis [1]. I don't think there is one for HornetQ. ActiveMQ comes out of the box. Artemis is a third party plugin but likely to be added OOTB in the future.

Those plugins can browse messages on the queue from a web browser. Mind there is some restrictions in the brokers itself how many messages back you can browse, and as well how much data you can see from big messages.

In the end a message broker is NOT a database. If you want to browse all messages anything then store the messages in a database.

- [1]: https://github.com/rh-messaging/artemis-hawtio